# Ruby's chunk method

Tags: ruby

I am reading Ruby Enumerable's `chunk` method on its documentation.
I want to know what every argument means.

So, it first opens a file. Does the second argument means look for its ACSII code?

|f| represents every line in the document?
then, line.ord is getting the ACSII of the first letter?

Then? I am not very sure the latter part.

reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html

```
open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r:iso-8859-1") { |f|
  f.chunk { |line| line.ord }.each { |ch, lines| p [ch.chr, lines.length] }
}
#=> ["\n", 1]
#   ["A", 1327]
#   ["B", 1372]
#   ["C", 1507]
#   ["D", 791]
#   ...
```

Comment: Please start by looking at the first example in the documentation. `chunk` does not open files, it only cares about things that are enumerable, which is what `open` returns. `chunk` passes each item received as it steps through the enumerable object (the file) into a block, and "chunks" elements based on the result of the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code uses multiple ruby methods in addition to `chunk` and you need to figure what each do to get a better understanding of what's going on, so let's take a look:

#### Ruby [File::Open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open):

> With no associated block, File.open is a synonym for ::new. If the
>   optional code block is given, it will be passed the opened file as an
>   argument and the File object will automatically be closed when the
>   block terminates. The value of the block will be returned from
>   File.open.

Syntax: `open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|file| block }`

In your case we opened a file at "/usr/share/dict/words" as an "iso-8859-1" format then we passed it to a block where we are doing more stuff with it

Which leads us to:

#### Ruby [Enumerable::Chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

> Enumerates over the items, chunking them together based on the return
>   value of the block. Consecutive elements which return the same block
>   value are chunked together.

Syntax: `somelist.chunk {|item_of_list| condition? }` ## output is chunks of items >> grouped by condition? result (still not clear >> check first example in docs)

#### Ruby [String::Ord](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-ord):

> Return the Integer ordinal of a one-character string
>   example `"a".ord         #=> 97`

Finally we have:

#### Ruby [Integer::Chr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

> Returns a string containing the character represented by the
>   receiver’s value according to encoding.

example `65.chr    #=> "A"`

#### How they play together:

1. We open a file containing english words and pass it to a block. **Output** >> is an an array of lines
2. We apply chunk on the file lines with an expression that calculates each character integer ordinal >> so for a line starting with a capital "A" the line.ord = 65. Now each line starting with "A" will be grouped in an array. **Output** >> is an array of objects containing [ordinal chr value (e.g 65) , array of items (lines) satisfying the condition (e.g line where ord = 65)
3. We loop and print the character each ord value represents (e.g "A" for 65) along with how many occurrences the character appeared (by counting the lines length)

#### Note (personal openion):

The example isn't the best and am not even sure about it's final goal! there must be easier ways to achieve this and explain how `chunk` works!

Got some idea? please improve this example ([Ruby Documentation](http://documenting-ruby.org/))

Answer (score 0):

I also agree bad examples were provide for #chunk of Enumerable. But the first example is more clear:

```
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5].chunk { |n|
  n.even?
}.each { |even, ary|
  p [even, ary]
}
#=> [false, [3, 1]]
#   [true, [4]]
#   [false, [1, 5, 9]]
#   [true, [2, 6]]
#   [false, [5, 3, 5]]
```

It groups consecutive elements which return the same block value. If the block value is the same but they are not consecutive, then a new group is created. The first index of the subarray is the return value of the block and the second is the collection of elements that consecutively had the same return value. Straight forward.

The next example is less clear, but has the same effect:

```
open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r:iso-8859-1") { |f|
  f.chunk { |line| line.ord }.each { |ch, lines| p [ch.chr, lines.length] }
}
#=> ["\n", 1]
#   ["A", 1327]
#   ["B", 1372]
#   ["C", 1507]
#   ["D", 791]
```

We do not know exactly what "/usr/share/dict/words" contains. The docs fail to disclose this information. Also Kernel module's open iterator passes a file object to its block. Apparently, the chunk iterator passes each line of the file to its block, similar to readlines (not readline). ord takes the integer codepoint of the FIRST character of the entire line. (As a sidenote, for unicode characters, I think it is safer to use mb_chars.ord). So just like the other example, this groups consecutive elements which return the same block value. Now chr takes that integer codepoint and converts it back to a character. Hence why the subarrays have a character at the first index and the total number of consecutive lines that match that character at the second index.